# Adding multiple users to an enterprise database in one go

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I couldn’t figure out how to add multiple users to an Enterprise database in one go.

Please consider the following situation:

1 ) I have an  enterprise database named “ Test02”

[image]

2) Then I try to add multiple users to it in one go, these users are stored before in the SQL server.

[image]

[image]

3) Now the problem that I can’t add them all to the database and I need to add each user alone and set a password to it.

[image]

Is there any method to see all users in the SQL server and add (all or some ) of them to the database.

Comment: There is a couple of ways to do this.  You could script it up in python using [CreateDatabaseUser_Management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Create_Database_User/00170000017r000000/) or you can create the users directly in the database using [CREATE USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545(v=sql.110).aspx).  Then [GRANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965(v=sql.110).aspx) the privileges mentioned on the first link.

Comment: Hi MickyT, thanks for your input, but my problem isn't with add a single user, the question is how to add the existing users in the SQL server security folder (U1,U2,U3,...) to the new database in one time without adding them one by one. and about python scripting unfortunately I do not have any experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a T-SQL way to dynamically add a set of users to a database and grant them permissions

**NOTE** I have no way of testing this at the moment, so there may be syntax errors and test it in an environment where it can't cause harm.

```
USE TestDatabase; --Make sure you have the right database

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'CREATE USER ' + name + ' FOR LOGIN ' + name + ';
' +
    'GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE VIEW, VIEW DEFINITION TO ' + name + ';
'
FROM sys.server_principals p
WHERE p.type in ('S','U') -- SQL Logins and Windows Login.  Do not change!
    and p.name in ('1','2','3'); -- List of names to add.  alter to suit

PRINT @sql; -- Show the statements being executed in the messages pane
EXEC(@sql); -- Run the statements that have been built
```

Make sure that you do not have any users mapped to the logins that you are adding.  A login can only be mapped to a single user in the database.

Comment: many thanks for the prompt help, I tried the script but it didn't worked with me, what maybe the problem in my case, Please have a look at this  ![Screenshot](http://s2.postimg.org/bsz39m7rd/Clip_3.jpg).

Comment: Hi micky, thanks a lot for your help, After executing the script successfully [screenShot](http://s16.postimg.org/bi938ggjp/Clip_5.jpg), Nothing happens and no user has been added to the database.

Comment: Many thanks Michy,It worked fine, but the users “1”.."2" didn’t appear in the users tab in the Test02 ![screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/qr5rq2ijf/Clip_6.jpg)database while if I hit properties on the User “1” and select user mapping the user have an access to the database![screenshot] ( http://s27.postimg.org/a3oxcebk3/Clip_7.jpg). 
The same thing when I add a database connection in ArcGIS the user “1” can connect to Test02 but the admin sa can’t see the user “1” in the privileges window to give him a privilege on the database![screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/jgjg5fgwr/Clip_9.jpg)

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh looking at your screenshots, it looks like you have removed the last line all together.  I have edited the answer to show what it should be.  Also it appears that you have user `s` mapped to login `1`.  It would be best if you remove this user before running he SQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21131/discussion-between-mickyt-and-ahmad-saleh).